Nodemailer & GoogleApis Oauth not working on AWS Amplify
Currently developing a Next.js app that has an API route to send an email. The route has a post that is using Nodemailer & Google OAuth to send an email. Currently when running locally it sends successfully & I receive it. However when deployed on AWS amplify the email is not received successfully however in the network tab in chromes inspector it shows a 200 success.
I am wondering what needs to be done for the email to be received successfully when deployed on AWS amplify & why it's working locally?
Thank you in advance for any & all assistance;
The app/api/email/route.ts code file including the post:
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const { email, name, userNote } = await request.json();
  // Create Transporter with Google OAuth2
  const createTransporter = async () => {
    console.log('inside createTransporter ~~~~~~~');
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground',
    );
    // obtain Refresh Token:
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    });
    // Obtain Access Token by calling getAccessToken
    const accessToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      oauth2Client.getAccessToken((err, token) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('----- Error here cannot getAccessToken boo ------', err);
          reject();
        }
        resolve(token);
      });
    });
    // Create transporter with OAuth2
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: process.env.NODEMAILER_MY_EMAIL,
        accessToken,
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
      },
    });

    return transporter;
  };
  // send secure google email
  const sendSecureGoogleMail = async () => {
    try {
      const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.NODEMAILER_MY_EMAIL,
        to: process.env.NODEMAILER_MY_EMAIL,
        subject: ` -  ‼  - YO K8 Message from ${name} (${email})`,
        text: userNote,
      };
      let emailTransporter = await createTransporter();
      await emailTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    } catch (err) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
      console.log('ERROR: ', err);
    }
  };
  // call send email
  try {
    await sendSecureGoogleMail();
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Email sent' });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

In the browser here is the network tab in chromes inspector:

